# Cycles baked texture is much darker

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking

Im trying to rebake texture from 1 uv to another. For some reason cycles decided to make textures darker then initial image(i baked it before in this same file and it was fine). Bake set to diffuse and only color is checked, no normal maps(its pretty much principled bsdf with color plugged in), no vertex color or anything. I've tried changing color set from filmic to standart, same thing. Oh and normals facing correct way. Here is the image of what texture looks like(right) before bake, and after(left)[image]

Comment: what exactly you wanna do?

Comment: When you set up your "bake texture" (the one you left selected in materials before the bake), did you set it to sRGB or Linear?

Comment: May be your reflection is not correct...

Comment: I forgot the tool but it is in mesh...

Comment: I'm trying to rebake it, so i can fit few textures into one(basically changed UV layout and baking from one UVmap to another) .     Texture is set to sRGB.

Answer (score -1):

If you are baking the Diffuse, use the Diffiuse node instead on the principled BSDF. It's worked for me.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can, [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)